# Composing a permutation with a transposition and length

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $\pi$ be an element of the permutation group $S_n$, such that, when it operates on the ordered set $\{1, 2, \ldots , N\}$, the ordered set that it produces $\{k_1, k_2, \ldots , k_N\}$ has two adjacent entries $k_i < k_{i+1}$, for some $i$.

Consider now the permutation $\pi'$ which is the composition of $\pi$ and the transposition of the $i$th and $(i+1)$-th entry, that is the permutation which operates on the ordered set $\{1, 2, \ldots , N\}$ to give $\{k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_{i+1},k_i, \ldots, k_N\}$.

Question: Is the length of $\pi$ always greater than the length of $\pi'$?

Edit: To clarify, by *length* of a permutation, I mean the minimal number transpositions a permutation can be expressed in terms of.

Comment: See this: https://rfgsemisimply.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/length-of-a-permutation/

Comment: "greater than $\pi$" seems to make little sense. Perhaps you meant "greater than that of $\pi$", but that would still make no sense -- perhaps there was also meant to be a prime on one of the $\pi$s?

Comment: The link cited by @ajotatxe uses an unusual notion of "length" which, to me, is better known as "absolute length". When I just hear the word "length" (of a permutation), I normally assume the Coxeter length is meant instead.

Comment: Either way, the answer to the question is "No", whatever notion of length is being used, because otherwise the length of $\pi$ would be greater than that of $\pi'$ but conversely the length of $\pi'$ would also be greater than that of $\pi$ (because transposing $i$-th and $i+1$-th entries in $\pi'$ would give back $\pi$).

Comment: What a transposition of two adjacent entries does to the Coxeter length depends on which of these two entries is larger. See (what is currently) Exercise 9 (a) in http://web.mit.edu/~darij/www/primes2015/sols.pdf . (If the numbering changes, search for "The only permutation having length 0" and scroll a bit down.) The solution of the exercise is the kind of straightforward argument that seems to blow up in size when forced onto paper, so I guess you can find it yourself faster than you can read mine.